# Solve system $m_av_a^2=m_a(v_a')^2+m_b(v_b')^2; m_av_a=m_av_a'+m_bv_b' $

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I'm doing a physics problem and I'm stuck on something that should be easy by now but yet I can't figure out how to solve this neatly. I've tried completing the square and the quadratic formula but the results get really ugly.

> \begin{align}m_av_a^2&=m_a(v_a')^2+m_b(v_b')^2\\
>  m_av_a&=m_av_a'+m_bv_b'\end{align}

The two unknowns are $v_a'$ and $v_b'$ but I only need $v_b'$. According to the notes the answer should be

$$v_b'=\frac{2m_av_a}{m_a+m_b}.$$

I don't see how $v_a'$ vanishes here. The answer I got was

$$v'_b=\sqrt{\frac{m_a}{m_b}(v_av_a'-(v_a')^2)-\frac{v_a^2}{4}}+\frac{v_a}{2}.$$

Any help is welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the second equation we get
$$v_a-\frac{m_b}{m_a}v_b'=v_a'$$

Plugging this in the first equation we get
$$m_av_a^2=$$
$$m_a\left(v_a-\frac{m_b}{m_a}v_b'\right )^2+m_bv_b'^2$$
Simplifying we get
$$0=\frac{m_b^2}{m_a}v_b'^2-2m_bv_b'v_a+m_bv_b'^2$$
we get
$$v_b'=\frac{2m_am_bv_a}{m_b^2+m_am_b}$$